# Why dividing long line (with lambda/interactive) in the (general.el) breaks off the Syntax coloring?

Tags: key-bindings, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, syntax

[image]

This is part of my [general el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el) config.
As shown in the image, when I divide long line (that has `lamda`, `interative`) into multiple lines `:which-key ......` changes color.`

1. Why is this happening?
2. Am I doing something wrong?
3. What is your preferred way to execute functions that has arguments such as `(org-latex-export-to-pdf nil t)` in `general el` config.

```
(use-package general
  :config
  (general-evil-setup t)

  (general-create-definer rune/leader-keys
    :keymaps '(normal insert visual emacs)
    :prefix "SPC"
    :global-prefix "C-SPC")
  )



(rune/leader-keys


  "oxp"  '(org-latex-export-to-pdf                                      :which-key "(o)-(x)port-(p)df")
  "oxP"   '((lambda () (interactive) (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil t))   :which-key "(o)-(x)port-subtree-(P)df")
  "oxsp"  '((lambda () (interactive)
              (org-latex-export-to-pdf nil t))  :which-key "(o)-(x)port-subtree-(P)df")
  )
```

---

Update:

Running bare `emacs -Q` shows same syntax color break as image below:
[image]

Update (2)
Apparently, if nothing before `:which-key` then syntax color is OK. I guess.

[image]

Comment: (I'm assuming the highlighting is from font-lock.) Track down the font-lock rules for the major mode. If you feel the rules aren't up to the job: `M-x report-emacs-bug` if you see the same thing without your init file, or report it to whatever library your init file is using that might be imposing inadequate font-lock rules.

Comment: Apparently, if `newline` is just before the `:which-key`. (i.e. only spaces before `:which-key`) then syntax coloring won't break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move to the red text and type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (`display-local-help`), or alternatively hover the mouse pointer over the text, you will see the following message:

> Easy to misread; consider moving the element to the next line

(Which comes from the `help-echo` text property on that text.)

You can also see that information by asking Emacs to tell you about the text at point with <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (`what-cursor-position`; see also `describe-char`).  This will additionally show you that the faces you expected to see *are* still present -- the initial syntax highlighting recognised everything correctly, but those faces are masked by the warning.

Essentially Emacs is pointing out that you have a sequence of expressions which are formatted over multiple lines and you *haven't* broken a line in a structurally-significant place between forms.  If the forms are all one line that's ok; but if you have a form which is formatted over multiple lines (the lambda in this case) and you then append an additional form on the *same line* as the final line of that multi-line form, it points it out as potentially being visually confusing (as, depending on circumstances, the trailing form may well *look* like a part of the multi-line form).

You can see the same with just the following:

```el
'((foo
   bar) baz)
```

The test which triggers this is named `lisp--match-hidden-arg` which gives you an idea of the thinking behind it.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks !